# The identity theorem applied

Tags: complex-analysis

## Problem

Let $E$ be a domain and let $f,g$ be analytic functions on $E$ such that $f(z)g(z)=0$ for all $z \in E$. Prove that either $f \equiv 0$ or $g \equiv 0$.

#### Proof

Let $E$ be a domain and let $f,g$ be analytic functions on $E$ such that $f(z)g(z)=0$ for all $z \in E$. Consider any sequence $\{z_i\}_1^\infty$ which converges in $E$. On this sequence $f(z)g(z)=0$ for all $i$. Since this is true on this sequence either $f(z_i)=0$ for all $i$ in which case $f(z) \equiv 0$, $g(z_i)=0$ for all $i$ and so $g(z) \equiv 0$ or the zeroes of the composite function are split amongst $f$ and $g$. Consider the subsequence $\{z \in \{z_i\}| f(z)=0\}$ and the subsequence  $\{z \in \{z_i\}| g(z)=0\}$. Since $f(z)g(z)=0$ for all $z \in E$ one or both of these must be infinite and thus be guaranteed to actually converge (obviously in $E$). In which case either $f(z) \equiv 0$, $g(z) \equiv 0$ or $f(z) \equiv 0$ and $g(z) \equiv 0$ by the identity theorem.

## Confusion

I believe the details above aren't spot on.

When applying the identity theorem do I need an infinite sequence which converges? This is my guess as then I could pick out finitely many zeroes and say things must be identically zero.

Do they need to follow a strict formulaic kind of sequence or may be they be picked by any criterion?

Comment: Your argument is correct. To apply your identity theorem to $f$, you need the zero set $Z(f)$ to have a limit point. Note that a sequence can have the same terms, so just any sequence is not enough. For a cleaner proof, take an infinite compact subset $K$ of $E$ (e.g., a closed disk), and prove that the zero set of either $f$ or $g$ must have a limit point in $E$.

Comment: I think you need to say something more about the number of points of $\{ z_j\}$, but it depends on your definition of limit point.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that $E$ is open and connected. Consider $C_f=\{z: f(z)=0\}$, $C_g=\{z:g(z)=0\}$. $C_f$ and $C_g$ are closed and $C_f\cup C_g=E$. This implies that the interior of $C_f$ or the interior of $C_g$ is not empty (you can use Baire theorem here). If the interior of $C_f$ is not empty, there exists $U\subset C_f$ open such that the restriction of $f$ to $U$ is zero. You can apply the identity theorem to show that $f=0$.

Comment: yes, but I believe the OP question was more about if his proof was correct than how to prove the result